# How to convert a string to character array in c (or) how to extract a single char form string?

Tags: c

I need to convert a string to a char array in C; how can I do this?

Or at least, how can I extract single chars from a string incrementally?

Comment: In C, a string is a character array.

Comment: Answewr to the first question: create array shorter by 1 and copy  chars from the string array to new array

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In C, a string is actually stored as an array of characters, so the 'string pointer' is pointing to the first character. For instance,

```
char myString[] = "This is some text";
```

You can access any character as a simple char by using myString as an array, thus:

```
char myChar = myString[6];
printf("%c\n", myChar); // Prints s
```

Hope this helps!
David

Answer (score 4):

In C, there's no (real, distinct type of) strings. Every C "string" is an array of chars, zero terminated.

Therefore, to extract a character c at index i from string your_string, just use

```
char c = your_string[i];
```

Index is base 0 (first character is your_string[0], second is your_string[1]...).

Comment: are they not null terminated.

Comment: '\0' (the null character) is defined to have integer value 0.

Comment: It's called ASCII*Z* for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

In this simple way

```
char str [10] = "IAmCute";
printf ("%c",str[4]);
```