# String to char with function

Tags: c, string, char

i want to get a string from the keyboard ,like "abcde" , and then insert it in a char,for example b which is char , but there is no function,like atoi(a) for integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char a[6];
    char b;
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("%s",a);
    printf("\n");
    b=a;
    printf("%c",b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: heh? whaddya mean by insert a string into a char?

Comment: `b=a[0]` instead of `b=a`

Comment: String "abcde" is not a number. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: b can store only a character.

Comment: I have to put some names to strings and then make an array with these names . But i cant put strings to an one  dimensional array

Comment: Do you mean a 2 dimensional array, like: `char [10][6]`? That can hold 10 strings of length 5.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert a string into a char. You can, however, convert the string to an array of chars. If this is what you are looking for, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867979/how-to-convert-a-string-to-character-array-in-c-or-how-to-extract-a-single-cha)